Finding Count of Similar Values Across Columns in Tableau
I would like to merge together two columns in Tableau which have similar values in order to get a bar graph that showcases the count of each value, while still maintaining the original values. I can not post workbok due to sensitivities, apologies. Sample data below.
Example data:
COLUMN1
Red
Red
Red
Orange
Blue
Green
COLUMN 2
Red
Blue
Blue
Orange
Green
DESIRED OUTPUT:
Red Count:4
Orange Count: 2
Blue Count: 3
Green Count:2
And represented as bar graph. Basically summing the occurrence of the values across two similar columns. I tried merge, but then i lose the original COLUMN 1 and COLUMN2 which I need. Hope this makes sense.

One approach is to pivot on your two columns - read about pivot in the tableau help.
The effect is that the table will appear to have twice the number of rows as the original, with the same information arranged differently.
Turning
...|Column1 | Column2 | ...
...| Red    |  Blue   | ...
...| Green  |  Red    | ...

into
...| Pivot Column | Pivot Value | ...
...| Column1      |  Red        | ...
...| Column2      |  Blue       | ...
...| Column1      |  Green      | ...
...| Column2      |  Red        | ...

You can now rename your columns if desired, and sum Pivot Values as needed.
There are other approaches, but this the simplest in most cases.
You can also have 2 Tableau data sources that point to the same original data source, where one is pivoted and the other is not. Then you can use whichever is more convenient for each worksheet, confident that both are simply different views of the same underlying data.
